# Quartz Scheduler - detecting when ThreadPool is exhausted?

Tags: java, threadpool, quartz-scheduler

We have a project with multiple schedulers and want to detect when the threadPool is maxed out on one scheduler - pick up the next triggered Job and schedule this Job on a separate 'overflow' scheduler, is this possible or worth doing?

How do you even detect when the threadPool is maxed out?